# Discord.py create a maximum of 1 channel per user

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
if message_id == 941751519781466172 and emoji == "":

    self.ticket_creator = user_id

    message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
    await message.remove_reaction("",user)

    member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
    support_role = guild.get_role(941751615998791740)
    category = guild.get_channel(941749835328012328)
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True),
        support_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
    }
    self.channel_ticket = await category.create_text_channel(f'övgü-{user.name}',  overwrites=overwrites)

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Yetkililer en yakın zamanda yardımcı olmak için sizinle iletişime geçecek lütfen bekleyiniz.\n"
              "Övgü satın alımı için ''Fiyatlar'' yazarak öğrenebilirsiniz.",
        color=0xf1c40f)

    msg = await self.channel_ticket.send(embed=embed)

    dmmessage = (f'Övgü kanalınız oluşturuldu. (SAĞDAKİ YAZIYA TIKLAGİT)=====> <#{self.channel_ticket.id}> ')

    dm = await user.send(dmmessage)
```

when the user clicks on the emoji in the message, it creates a private text channel for him and send a dm message that private channel has been created. a new channel is created every time the user clicks on it, how can I block it ?

if the user has created a private channel, I want him to send a dm message because you have already created a private channel.

nickname of the user becomes the name of the channel.

Comment: you can add the user's id to an array (or 
a dictionary or a json or a database) and check if the user's id is in the array everytime you create a channel
so if it is not there you can make the channel but if it is there send them a dm and say that they already have one open private channel

Comment: i don't understand much from json or a database. How can i do ?

Comment: you can just add it to an array you don't need to bother with a json file or database for now

Comment: could you please can you send sample code

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array to store the user id's on creation and only create a channel if the user id is not already in there. Like I mentioned you can also use [a `.json` file](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp) or a [database](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp). The reason you would want to use one of these instead of a plain array is so that it is stored even if your script is turned off (say for maintenance purposes) the list of open channels will still be stored unlike in a plain array where it will get reset.

```py
open_user_channels = []

if message_id == 941751519781466172 and emoji == "" and user_id not in open_user_channels:

    self.ticket_creator = user_id

    message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
    await message.remove_reaction("",user)

    member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
    support_role = guild.get_role(941751615998791740)
    category = guild.get_channel(941749835328012328)
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True),
        support_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
    }

    self.channel_ticket = await category.create_text_channel(f'övgü-{user.name}',  overwrites=overwrites)

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Yetkililer en yakın zamanda yardımcı olmak için sizinle iletişime geçecek lütfen bekleyiniz.\n"
              "Övgü satın alımı için ''Fiyatlar'' yazarak öğrenebilirsiniz.",
        color=0xf1c40f)

    await self.channel_ticket.send(embed=embed)

    dmmessage = (f'Övgü kanalınız oluşturuldu. (SAĞDAKİ YAZIYA TIKLAGİT)=====> <#{self.channel_ticket.id}> ')

    await user.send(dmmessage)
     
    open_user_channels.append(user_id)
 
else:
    await user.send("There is an open channel already.")
```

Comment: as you said, it doesn't work when you reset it, how can I do this could you please with json can you send its sample code?

Comment: `with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(user_id, f)` i am writing the userid to the json data with this code, instead of writing the userids to one under the other, it overwrites the previous userid

Comment: you will need to append it instead

Comment: I fix it thanks